# Fail to install Spyder 3.3.6 in Anaconda with Python 3.5 version

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I created a new environment in Anaconda choosing Python 3.5 as the version. As I continue installing the Spyder software through clicking the "Install" button within Anaconda interface, I receive the following message:

python==3.3.6 cannot be installed on this environment. Do you want to install the package in an existing environment or...."

I even tried clicking setting → install specific version → and choose other versions yet wit the same warning.

Appreciate your very kind help

Comment: on the [spyder github repo](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder#dependencies), it says that requirement is Python > 3.5 - so I'd expect the warning... if you have scripts that require Python 3.5, consider running them from somewhere else, not out of Sypder.

Comment: @MrFuppes thank you. Yet I am python beginner and I am only familiar with Anaconda. Do you mean that Spyder cannot run python <=3.5? Seems unreasonable to me because Spyder ran on python 2.7 in the past? Sorry If my question is confusing? But i do appreciate your kind help and response

Comment: no worries; Python 2 and Python 3 are completely different, so code for Python 2.7 likely won't run on Python 3.x. [Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder) is mainly written in Python, so if it uses features only available in Python > 3.5, you won't be able to install it in an environment that uses Python 3.5. However, it may be possible to use Python 3.5 *as interpreter* in Spyder (Preferences -> Python-Interpreter -> select custom interpreter). Why do you have to use Python 3.5 in the first place?

Comment: @MrFuppes it is because I needed to use the zipline library and obviously zipline requires python 3.5.

Comment: @MrFuppes Also, in Anaconda It doesnt allow me to install Jupyter after changing to python 3.5. Can I suspect this is for the same reason you mentioned?

Comment: If you rely on zipline, consider using it in a virtual environment with Py3.5 as interpreter. I don't use Anaconda/conda so not sure if/how that works with that distro. It's definitely possible using a normal Python installation + pip/venv (or pipenv). Can't guarantee though that you'll be able to use Spyder then.

Comment: @MrFuppes Allow me to ask a stupid question given I am new to Python. How does pip differ from Anaconda? I never know I can access to Python without Anaconda? I came across programming via the Excel days. So, to me Anaconda is like the Excel software and I have no idea how you use spreadsheet without excel?

Comment: Well there are some python packages that read/write Excel files ;-) Find some info on Anaconda [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42096280/how-is-anaconda-related-to-python). So imho Anaconda is mostly for convenience, but can be impractical for special cases like yours. `pip` is the package manager that comes with the standard installation from python.org

Comment: @MrFuppes thanks Fuppes. I am going to study about python.org in greater details. Now that I already have Anaconda installed (of course also other associated libraries like pandas, numpy....), do i still need to re-install everything from python.org or this could result in unexpected corruption?

Comment: I'd not recommend using multiple Python distributions in parallel. That can cause unexpected consequences / complications. Either a standard installation (manage packages with pip/pipenv) or Anaconda or WinPython etc. While you're at it, also check out virtual environments. Might be a bit much in the beginning but pays off in the end.